# Owl carousel 2 not working in responsive mode even after using responsiveclass true

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I plugged in owl carousel to my html page. It is working fine in desktop but when resized, looks like the images are getting resized but the carousel is not shrinking. Below is the screenshot of the issue when the next arrow is clicked and there are no more items next.

[image]

And below is the screenshot on load of the page when no prev or next arrows are clicked.

[image]

Below is my script. Can anyone please help me on how we can resize the carosel window to be responsive.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        //loop: true,
        items : 1,
        margin: 10,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navText:["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"],
        responsiveClass:true,
        responsive : {
            0:{
                items:1,
                nav:true
            },
            600:{
                items:2,
                nav:false
            },
            1000:{
                items:3,
                nav:true,
                loop:false
            }
        },
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I removed "carousel-wrap" class on tHE parent div in my HTML and it worked. It worked because in css, tHis class Has a fixed widtH of 1000px